# Is a group a normal subgroup of itself?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, normal-subgroups

I know this might sound very stupid, but is a group $G$ a normal subgroup of itself? I would say yes. For a subgroup $H<G$ the following is equivalent that for all $a\in G$:

i) $aH=Ha$

ii) $aHa^{-1}\subset H$

iii) $aHa^{-1}= H$

but for $a\in G$ we have that $aGa^{-1}\subset G$ and $G$ is a subgroup of itself.

Am I right or did I do a mistake somewhere?

Comment: You may also note that there's only one right lateral and one left lateral, $G$ itself in both cases, and so left laterals coincide with right laterals which is one possible characterization of normal subgroup. Also, if we denote $\epsilon:G\rightarrow\{0\}$ the constant homomorphism we have $G=\ker(\epsilon)$ and kernels are always normal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you are right. Every non-trivial group $G$ always has at least two normal subgroups: $G$ itself and $\{e_G\}$.

Comment: thank you for the quick response! I will accept the answer in 10 min, I have reached my limit :)